# Get Indexes of Filtered Array Items

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, filter

In JavaScript, I have the following array

```
var arr = [5, 10, 2, 7];
```

From that array, I would like to get an array containing only the indexes of the items that are less than 10. So, in the above example, the indexes array would be

```
var indexes = [0, 2, 3];
```

Now, I want something simlar to `filter`, but that would return the indexes.

If I try `filter`, this is how it will work

```
var newArr = arr.filter(function (d) {
    return (d < 10);
});

// newArr will be: [5, 2, 7];
```

This is not what I want. I want something along the following lines **(note this is a pseudo-code)**

```
var indexes = arr.filter(function (d) {
    /* SOMETHING ALONG THE FOLLOWING PSEUDOCODE */
    /* return Index of filter (d < 10); */
});

// indexes will be: [0, 2, 3];
```

How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: @Li357 - I tried this. It will not work. Because the map will be indexed to the new filtered array, which will cause shifted indexes.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Greeso ... `filter` doesn't mutate the original array. You can still use the original array `arr` to get the indexes from the filtered array.

Comment: Well, what if the original array has items with the same value. Then it will not work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a reducer.

```js
var arr = [5, 10, 2, 7];

var newArr = arr.reduce(function(acc, curr, index) {
  if (curr < 10) {
    acc.push(index);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);


console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `forEach` loop:

```js
const arr = [5, 10, 2, 7];


const customFilter = (arr, min) => {
  const result = [];
  arr.forEach((element, index) => {
    if (element < min) {
      result.push(index);
    }
  });
  
  return result;
}

console.log(customFilter(arr, 10));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array#reduce` and add indexes whose value is greater than 10.

```js
var arr = [5, 10, 2, 7];
var indexes = arr.reduce((r, d, i) => d < 10 ? (r.push(i), r) : r , []);
console.log(indexes);
```