# How To Return Values from one array when values from another array are selected by users in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm a new student of programming and I'm trying to figure out an assignment.

I have to write a function that returns values from one array when values from another array are selected by the user on a one-to-one basis.

I've tried the following among other things and it gives a reference error (Apple is not defined; but Apple is an element in the first array).

```
var valueFromSelect = Apple;

  for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++){
    if(valueFromSelect == fruits[i]){
      console.log(prices[i]);
      break
```

In short, I want to return a price for each fruit that is selected. Here are the arrays:

```
var fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Pear", "Pineapple", "Strawberry", "Blueberry"];
var prices = [1.50, 1.20, 1.05, 1.10, 3.00, 0.40, 0.10]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you want `Apple` to be a *string value*: `var valueFromSelect = 'Apple';`.  Your code tries to assign the *value* of the *variable* `Apple` to the variable `valueFromSelect`  and the error tells you that such a variable (`Apple`) doesn't exist.

Comment: Is Apple supposed to be a variable or a string?

Comment: @FelixKling, thanks for responding. Do I just need to enclose with quotes then? My confusion comes from the fact that Apple is one of the string values in the first array.

Comment: @MikeMapanare, it's supposed to be a spring

Answer (score 0):

`Apple` value must be a `string` if your array contain strings.

```
var valueFromSelect = "Apple";
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple"];
```

---

PS : You can simplify your code by using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method (from Array prototype) like bellow :

```
var valueFromSelect = "Apple";
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple"];
var result = fruits.filter(fruit => valueFromSelect == fruit);
```

This will return you an `Array` containing each values who matched with items in your Array. so if `result.length > 0` you can consider your parameter as 'matched'.

Comment: I tried this code just now, but I have "undefined" where I want there to be a price. I feel like I'm missing something. How do I bring in the array for "prices" here?

Comment: You need get the index of your array by using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) or a foreach method, you have a  [good example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47917535/get-indexes-of-filtered-array-items/47917584)

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because in order for JS to understand `Apple` is a string you have to surround it with `"` (double quotes) or `'` (quotes).

The way it is right now, is telling JS to save into `valueFromSelect` the value stored in something called `Apple` which you have not defined yet.

Examples:

- `'Apple'`
- `"Apple"`

This way it should work:

```
var valueFromSelect = 'Apple';

  for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++){
    if(valueFromSelect == fruits[i]){
      console.log(prices[i]);
      break
```

Since you want a function that prints the price of a given fruit, you need to create a function that receives the selected fruit as a parameter:

```
function printFruitPrice(valueFromSelect) {
    for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++){
        if(valueFromSelect == fruits[i]){
          console.log(prices[i]);
          break
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
printFruitPrice('Apple');
```

Comment: thanks very much. I tried that, but it only provides a value for that one string. There are other fruits in the first array. It keeps returning the same price for them all when I change the fruits.

Comment: @DaringDeer Please, check out my updated answer.

Comment: just did. Want to try it out now. Will revert in a bit.